# How to run threads in parallel

Tags: jmeter

The stress test plan contains 5 threads, see below.

Lets consider a food booking app :

- Thread 0 contains the prerequisites such as extracting the token which will be used by the remaining threads (1,2,3,4).
- Thread 1 relates to the food menu.
- Thread 2 relates to adding items to the menu and calculating the order price.
- Thread 3 creates the order.
- Thread 4 confirms the order.

Each thread requires the previous thread to be executed as it uses the response from the previous thread and I have been asked to run Thread 1,2,3,4 concurrently, but the fact is they cannot be run concurrently as
Thread 3 cannot be executed without actually executing Thread 2 and so on.
7.

Let me add a real-world use case:

- A user is viewing the menu items
- Concurrently, another user is confirming the order
- Another user is adding items to the cart

Actually, all the operations are taking place concurrently, but no operation can be performed by skipping the previous threads.

How do I make changes to my script to accommodate such type of parallel stress testing?

Comment: "... I have been asked to ..." By whom? Why don't you ask that person to clarify what they meant.

Answer (score 0):

Had to re-read your question a few times... I think what you are asking is can you run multiple "Thread Groups" ... the answer is yes, in your test plan you right-click and add multiple Thread Groups, each thread Group has its own user journey scripted.

As for dependencies between Thread Groups there are options for sharing variables. but you would likely need to work out your logic and write a little bit of groovy to ensure that the data flows correctly.

You could also look at "How to Use the Inter-Thread Communication Plugin in JMeter" on the BlazeMeter website: https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-use-the-inter-thread-communication-plugin-in-jmeter

---

Update: After Christian's formatting of the question, it appears that "threads 0-4" are describing a *user journey*. for example; user logs in, clicks menu, adds item x, goes to checkout etc.

This would be recorded in one Thread Group. Each call made would provide a server response that could then be parameterised and correlated, ensuring data is passed appropriately. The "concurrency" would come from ramping up multiple users "Threads".

For example; here in this screenshot, I have added a Thread Group that has 4 HTTP Samplers (the user journey). The Thread Group is then set to run 10 users, ramping up in 5 minutes (300 seconds), and runs for a duration of 3600 seconds (aka 1 hour).

[image]

Comment: "Had to re-read your question a few times" I tried to simplify the question formating for you and all other readers.